# Custom UIAlertView iOS8 xCode6

Tags: xcode, uiview, ios8, uialertview

Hello everyone I'm trying to create my AlertView customized using a simple class UIView.

to call my alert in the Implementation desired file using the following code

```
UTAlertView * alert = [[UTAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @ "Hello how are you" message: @ "test message"];

     alert.types = UTAlertViewTypeError;
     [alert presentAlert];
     [self.view addSubview: alert];
```

As you see, to select the type of color for all'alert, use

```
alert.types = UTAlertViewType
```

I thought I did everything correctly but I can not see the different colors "Types" assigns the UIView of Alert ...

Can you tell me if I've done something wrong?

this is the .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UIColor+UTAlertView_Color.h"


typedef NS_ENUM (NSInteger, UTAlertViewType) {

UTAlertViewTypeSuccess,
UTAlertViewTypeError,
UTAlertViewTypeWarning };


@interface UTAlertView : UIView

-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)title message:(NSString *)message;
-(void)presentAlert;


@property(nonatomic, assign) UTAlertViewType types;


@end
```

and this is the file.m

```
@interface UTAlertView ()
@property (nonatomic, strong)UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong)UILabel *messageLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong)UIImageView *alertIcon;
@property (nonatomic, strong)UIView *alertView;



@end

@implementation UTAlertView
@synthesize alertIcon;
@synthesize titleLabel, messageLabel;
@synthesize alertView;
@synthesize types;


-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)title message:(NSString *)message  {

    alertView                         = [self initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kPositionX, 0, kSizeW, 55)];

    titleLabel                        = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    titleLabel.textColor              = [UIColor titleColor:1];
    titleLabel.font                   = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    titleLabel.text                   = title;
    titleLabel.frame                  = CGRectMake(2, 3, 50, 10);
    [self addSubview:titleLabel];

    messageLabel.textColor            = [UIColor messageColor:1];
    messageLabel.font                 = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    messageLabel.text                 =  message;



    return self;
}


-(UTAlertViewType)types {

switch (types) {
    case UTAlertViewTypeSuccess:
    alertView.backgroundColor    = [UIColor successColor:1];
        break;
        case UTAlertViewTypeError:
        alertView.backgroundColor    = [UIColor errorColor:1];
        break;
        case UTAlertViewTypeWarning:
        alertView.backgroundColor    = [UIColor warningColor:1];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}


return types;
```

}
 I'm using the correct Type enum? something else am I doing wrong? .. Thank you very much for your help

The background of UiView is Transparent

Comment: You've implemented a property getter that looks like it wants to use the current value to set the background colour.  It doesn't look like you call the getter anywhere.  (I'm not sure what "types" is when you say `switch (types) {` or `return types` because I would expect the backing variable for the property to be `_types`.)

Comment: excuse but are new to xcode ... could you give me an example more 'clear perhaps through the code ?? I could not understand you ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this `alert.types = UTAlertViewTypeError;`, it is the same as `[alert setTypes: UTAlertViewTypeError]`.

If you want to cause it to change the background, you need to write the code in a `-(void)setTypes:(UTAlertViewType)t {` method instead of a `-(UTAlertViewType)types {` method.